# Ternary operations: "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, conditional-operator

```
df.mto_mts = "MTO" if df.MTO_STRAT == "" else "MTS" if df.MTO_STRAT == "Z5" else "SS"
```

I've seen answers about `|` vs `or` - I guess the else condition may be a hidden or operation that is breaking things? What's a better way to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python `if-else` statement is not capable of handling Pandas series of boolean array, hence the error.  You have to use either Pandas or Numpy functions which can handle series in vectorized way.

In this case, you can use [`np.select()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) as follows:

```
import numpy as np

condlist = [df.MTO_STRAT == "", df.MTO_STRAT == "Z5"]
choicelist = ["MTO", "MTS"]
df.mto_mts = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default="SS")
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior is to broadcast the comparison operator, yielding a series consisting of boolean values for each comparison. That is, `df.MTO_STRAT == ""` basically gives `pd.Series([_ == "" for _ in df.MTO_STRAT])`. You're trying to have the ternary evaluated for each element individually, and have the broadcasting be done at the level of the entire statement, rather than at the comparison level, but Python doesn't know that's what you want to do.

To tell it to do that, there are several methods. One is

```
df.mto_mts = pd.Series([
    "MTO" if _ == "" 
         else "MTS" if _ == "Z5" 
             else "SS" 
    for _ in df.MTO_STRAT])`
```

A more Pythonic form of this is

```
df.mto_mts = df.MTO_STRAT.apply(lambda x: 
    "MTO" if x == "" else "MTS" if x == "Z5" else "SS")
```

Since you're selecting a value for `mto_mts` based on `df.MTO_STRAT`, another option is to just use a dictionary:

```
mts_lookup = ["": "MTO", "Z5": "MTS"]
df.mto_mts = df.MTO_STRAT.apply(lambda x: mts_lookup.get(x, "SS"))
```